# how to do reduce multiple query into one query

Tags: mysql

```
Query 1: select item_no from hdd where item_no='$in' and id != '$id'

Query 2: select sr from hdd where sr='$hd'

Query 3: select item_no from hdd where casing_no='$c' and id != '$id'
```

Result Required :

```
Q1 = num_rows = 0
Q2 = num_rows <> 0
Q3 = num_rows = 0
```

How can perform above task in single query ? ?

Done this :

```
SELECT id FROM hdd WHERE status='1' AND item_no='$in' AND FIND_IN_SET('$hd', sr)<>0 AND casing='$c' AND id<>'111'
```

Comment: Use or condition instead of and

Comment: What are your desired results?

Answer (score 2):

maybe try

```
SELECT id FROM hdd
WHERE ( (id <> '$id' AND (item_no = '$in' OR casing_no = '$c') ) OR sr='$hd');
```

the breakdown of the where column is

where 
EITHER

    --id is not equal to '$id' AND it matches either item_no = '$in' or it matches casing_no = '$c'
OR 
--to match the second query, sr='$hd'

Answer (score 1):

Could this provide the information you want?

```
select sum(item_no='$in' and id <> '$id') as Query1,
       sum(sr = '$hd') as Query2,
       sum(casing_no='$c' and id <> '$id')
from hdd;
```